# Inline everything inside div bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to align horizontally a h2 and bottom inside of a div using bootstrap and css. My code is below.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
     Use this form to update your profile.
  </div>
<div>
   <h3>Personal info</h3>
   <button class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Edit</button>
 </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: add display:inline to h3, and button

Comment: "inline" or "align"?

Comment: Thanks Maciej stilling learning css

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<div class="check">
   <h3>Personal info</h3>
   <button class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Edit</button>
 </div>  

.check h3,.check button{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0nvvce9/2/)